# How to render a hyperlink in a component template in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an Angular 6 application where a component is used to display a message on the page. Some of the messages contain hyperlinks embedded in them (in HTML markup). However, when the messages are displayed on the page, they are getting displayed in plain text (hyperlinks are not rendered, but the markup is displayed to the user instead).

You can visit Stackblitz @ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jj5nms for a sample application that I created to explain the issue.

Expected message display:

> Click [here](http://www.google.com).

Actual message display:

> Click <a href='http://www.google.com'>here</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to render HTML a then you need to bind to the `innerHTML` property of an element, for example:

```
<p [innerHTML]=“message | async”></p>
```

Where `message` is your observable from the service.

Using handlebars to render `message` is just rendering plain text, binding to `innerHTML` and using the `async` will render your html content

Answer (score 4):

You can use `innerHTML`

In your component:

```
linkHtml = "Click <a href='http://www.google.com'>here</a>"
```

In your template:

```
<div [innerHTML]="linkHtml"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:
in your .ts file :

```
dummyLinkText: string = "Click <a href='https://www.google.com'>here</a>";
```

and in your .html file:

```
<div [innerHTML]="dummyLinkText | translate"></div>
```